# How to see that a scheduled task is started manually, but not by the timer in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

In Nopcommerce a Scheduled task is normally started by a timer, but you also have the possibility to start it manually.

Is it possible in to make a distinction in the code, whether a task is started by a timer or it is started manually?

In my case I want a task to only run on Saterdays because its a large batchjob:

```cs
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
   return; // Don't do the task
}
```

But I would like to start and run it manually if the situation demands it.

```cs
bool StartedManually = _Some_magic_here_Please; // <- what to do here?
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && !StartedManually)
{
   return; // Don't do the task
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported without any source code modification, furthermore TaskManager and TaskThread classes do not implement any interface and they are not registered via the IoC container so you cannot make the required changes without changes in the Nop.Services project, there is no posibility for an add-on or extension.

You can workaround this by duplicating your task, you can keep a task with the weekdays constraints enabled in the scheluder and the other task with no weekdays constraints disabled (just for manual execution). A disabled task can be launched from the administration

It is not the cleanest solution but it requires just a little bit changes inheriting one task implementation from another.

Answer (score 0):

For the run task on Saturdays just set the period to 604800 seconds (7 days) and start the task for the first time on Saturday (change any properties and restart the application). Running the task manually does not affect the schedule.
Thus you don't need any specific logic in your task execution.

Comment: HI @RomanovM. Thanks for your answer. But you didn't get the point in the question, can you distinguish if a job is started manually or not.